# Changing location of sqlite database on rpi running django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, web, raspberry-pi

I am running a django project on a raspberry pi and want to move the database to an external hard drive that is connected. my settings looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/mnt/MOCStorage/database.db,
    }
}
```

When I run manage.py migrate, I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I have mounted the drive to /mnt/MOCStorage and used chmod to change the permissions of /mnt and /mnt/MOCStorage to 775.

How can I get this database to work here?

Comment: I don't know if it is true now, but back in the days sqlite was creating journal file in the same directory, where the database file is. 
That means the user who runs manage.py would require write permissions on the parent directory
 as well.

Comment: both directories should be writable. I tried chmod 777 on both directories and still am not getting anything to work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've missed the closing quotation:

```
'NAME': '/mnt/MOCStorage/database.db,
```

should read:

```
'NAME': '/mnt/MOCStorage/database.db',
```

However I would suspect this should throw a different error from the one you've mentioned, and this error may just be in your quote.

In which case perhaps try `touch /mnt/MOCStorage/database.db` as the webapp user to confirm write perms.